# Best Practices : What to use, .Net Class or short name?

Tags: c#

In C# we have .Net class and the short names, like Double and double. I was suggested sometime back that we shall use the short name always, wanted to know why. **I know they both are same**, but why one is sometimes preferred over others? Just readability or is there something more to it?

For example if I am creating a Class having a string and a boolean properties, which of the following should be used always and when the other should be used:

```
Class MyClass {
    ...
    private String x;
    private Boolean y;
    ...
}
```

OR

```
Class MyClass {
    ...
    private string x;
    private bool y;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Double and double are not entirely the same...

Comment: @Styxxy: Wrong.  This is C#, not Java.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000517/c-sharp-stylecop-sa1121-usebuiltintypealias-readability-rules for StyleCop  rule discussion

Comment: @MaxYakimets Oh Thanks :) that was very very useful :), So ultimately it's a personal choice, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: Do it like you want.

I would prefer to use the alias every time I can.

Use `Int32` instead of int when you have several different Ints in your Code. Like mixing `Int32`, `Int64` or `Int16`.

Comment: Richter says that using real names is more clear for people that use many languages(not only C#). And I think he is right.

Comment: Yes of course, but imagine you have a code block where you use mixed  `short`, `int`, `long` etc. it would be more easy to understand using `Int16`, `Int32` and `Int64`

Comment: So? I said the same thing — using real names (not aliases).

Comment: Ah sorry then I got you wrong. My fault.

Answer (score 3):

Well, they are the same.
After compilation to CLR they both point to same datatype.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either Int32 or int in your code, but you should use it in a convenient way, you shouldn't use them both, it can make the code unreadable, but C# conventions say that you should use synonyms always.

Some times, you may mix between "[Wrapper Classes](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=22183)" those are in Java, and "[Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)" in .Net, or 
"[Type Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885048/type-synonyms-in-c) of C#"

In C# "int" and "Int32" are the same, "bool and "Boolean" are the same, "string" and "String" are the same, but "int" is the synonymous in C# language of "System.Int32" class of .Net.

You can use "int?" or Nullable<int> to make the variable accept "null" value but in Java you should use the wrapper class Integer instead of integer to hold 'null' values.

Answer (score 3):

That is entirely dependent on you. For some readability is more imporatant. So use the one which is more readable and convinient to you.

Aliases are just used because of there convinience but they are the same as the actual ones for compilers.

Answer (score 3):

string is an alias for System.String, bool is an alias for System.Boolean and so on.
The C# type keywords and their aliases are interchangeable.

I personally prefer the usage of aliases unless I need to emphasize the explicit type in case this information may be needed in the future. Such as using System.Int32 instead if int to *explicitly* show that there's a limitation, even if they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

You should you use class name when you need to access static methods and short name when declaring a variable/field of given type.

```
int i = 0;
Int32.TryParse(s, out i);
```

See any of the Microsoft code samples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx

There is no difference in compiled code from doing it any other way. It is just cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Where did you see this convention of C#?

Comment: @MSakherSawan that is the format MS usually use in their sample code.

Comment: You may be right, but I can show you many microsoft samples using int.TryParse instead of Int32.TryParse, but it seams that there is no convention for this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384043.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`int`, `bool`, `string`, etc. are only aliases of predefined types in the `System` namespace.

Full list here: [Built-in types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types).